# pass numpy as argument in python flask give an error

Tags: python, numpy, flask

in the below code want to append one element in numpy using flask but it's give error

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(150)
b = 67
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/add')
def add():
    if(b):
        a = np.append(a,[b])
        return "number add successfully"
    else:
        return "number not added" 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**give an error**

```
builtins.TypeError

TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

please help to resolve this query.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is expecting `a` to be a local variable within it. In your case, you have defined `a` and `b` as global variables, outside iof the function. Just explicitly pass this information to your function by using `global a, b`. Like so

```
@app.route('/add')
def add():
    global a, b
    if(b):
        a = np.append(a,[b])
        return "number add successfully"
    else:
        return "number not added"
```

Comment: Thanks for solution